# How to use window lag in Scala Spark to find change

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
+----+------+
|day | count|
+----+------+
|   1|    50|
|   2|    55|
|   3|    53|
+----+------+
```

I want a table that looks like this:

```
+----+------+-------+
|day | count| delta |
+----+------+-------+
|   1|    50|      0|
|   2|    55|      5|
|   3|    53|     -2|
+----+------+-------+
```

I'm very new to Scala and here is what I'm trying, but it is wrong. My `prev_count` is null.

```
myDf.withColumn("prev_count", lag("count", 1)
              .over(Window.partitionBy("day")
              .orderBy("day"))).show()

val result = myDf.withColumn("change",
                            (myDf("count") - myDf("prev_count"))).show()
```

Pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't use the new column:

```
val withPrevcount = myDf.withColumn("prev_count", lag("count", 1).over(Window.partitionBy("day").orderBy("day")))

val result = withPrevcount.withColumn("change", col("count") - col("prev_count")))

result.show()
```

Comment: You are right, I wasn't using the new column, but I'm still not getting anything in the "prev_count" column. It is null after running your first line: "val withPrevcount = myDf.withColumn("prev_count", lag("count", 1).over(Window.partitionBy("day").orderBy("day")))
"

Comment: @b-ryce I think it should have been `col("count") - col("prev_count")` -- check if that fixes your problem. If not, it's probably a good idea to ask a new question focused on your new problem: I don't know enough about spark to debug any more than the basics.